# when I render animation some frame looks damaged in cycle

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, error, motion-capture

[image]

first, my English is bad. sorry,
when I render animation and play the video
it seems to be goes well but in some frame(randomly change every render)
chracter looks like cracked(Bunny in the middle) like photo above.
only chracters images are crack not other oject.
to make chracters movement I used Mixamo's Motion capture data

Comment: it's no problem that your english isn't good. You can use translate tools for that. But...you nearly gave us no useful information about what you did or what your settings are. So i recommend you provide your blend file so we can check it out ourselves.

Comment: Or, a file stripped don to just one character, on https://blend-exchange.com/